# Can I load data into Core Data but only when the user launches the app for the very first time?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an app that has the user interacting with cooking ingredients. For now, the ingredients that the user can choose from will be sourced from a text file in the app. When the app is first launched, I want the ingredients to be loaded from the text file and each one to become an instance of the IngredientItem entity that I setup in my Core Data model. I think I am close however I am receiving an error:

`The operation couldn't be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.)`

I'm currently trying to load data into Core Data in the app's root view. I do so by attaching my `loadIngredientsIfNeeded()` function in the `.onAppear()` event of the ContentView. I check whether the data has been loaded before by checking if a user defaults key of `dataLoaded` exists (and if it's false). If false, I iterate through the text file, extract each line and attempt to create an instance of the IngredientItem. I've added some print statements around the function. It seems to be struggling in the following line `try moc.save()` (where moc is managedObjectContext)

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

@main
struct PantryApp: App {
    @StateObject private var dataController = DataController()
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
                .onAppear(perform: loadIngredientsIfNeeded)
            
        }
    }

    func loadIngredientsIfNeeded() {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        print(defaults)
        
        if !defaults.bool(forKey: "dataLoaded") {
            print("First time load. Loading data")
            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Ingredients", withExtension: "txt") else {
                fatalError("Ingredients.txt not found")
            }
                
        
            if let ingredients = try? String(contentsOf: url) {
                let ingredientNames = ingredients.split(separator: "\n")
        
                // Refactor
                for name in ingredientNames {
                    let ingredient = IngredientItem(context: moc)
                    ingredient.id = UUID()
                    ingredient.name = String(name)
                    
                    print("Setup \(name) complete")
                }
        
                do {
                    try moc.save()
                    print("Moc save successful")
                    defaults.set(true, forKey: "dataLoaded")
                    print("Default save successful")
                } catch {
                    print("Error saving ingredients: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Print `error` instead of `error.localizedDescription` as it might give more infos.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think your issue is that you have not yet created your `moc` when you are attempting to use it. Paul Hudson has a great [post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-configure-core-data-to-work-with-swiftui) at HackingWithSwift.com that will walk you through it. Essentially, you need to create the context first, and then inject it into the environment. It will definitely never be available in the environment for `@main`. However, once you create it, you can use that value in your function and to inject into the environment.

Comment: @Yrb Thank you! And yes I believe that was the case. I moved the loadIngredientsIfNeeded function to the ContentView instead of main and it started working!

Answer (score 0):

From my research it seems that here I was trying to access my managedObjectContext before I could use it. Instead of having the loadIngredientsIfRequired function in my main root view, I moved it to the one below (ContentView) and passed the moc through to that and it started working.